# Copying content from one file to another file,without copying the existing content

Tags: java, file-io

I have one file1 and I want to copy its content to another fil2e. After that I have added some content to file1. Now I want to append the newly added part in file1 to file2, so that the two files remain in sync. Initially I thought of checking byte by byte but that is very inefficient for large files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write detailed description of your files used. Are you using text files or what

Comment: Determine the length of file2, seek to that position in file1 and start copying  from there.

Comment: you can read file 1 and save it as string, then read file 2 and save it as string as well. now you can take the substring of file 1, starting at file2.length and append it to file 1

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache Common's FileUtils which you can download here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

It provides you with several methods to read from and write into files which should help to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileChannel.transferTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo-long-long-java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel-):

```
Path file1 = /* ... */ ;
Path file2 = /* ... */ ; 

try (FileChannel channel1 = FileChannel.open(file1);
     FileChannel channel2 = FileChannel.open(file2,
        StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {

    channel1.transferTo(channel2.size(), Long.MAX_VALUE, channel2);
}
```